# What's the selection criterion for the "best" model in "regsubsets" & how do I access several "best" models?

Tags: subset, linear-regression, feature-selection

I've been playing around with the **regsubsets** function a bit, using the **"forward" method** to select variables for a linear regression model. However, despite also reading the documentation I can't seem to figure out, how the leaps.setup underlying this function determines the "best" model for each separate number of variables in a model.

Say I have a model with potential 10 variables in it (and nvmax = 10), I get exactly one "best" model for a model with 1 var, 2 vars etc. **But** **how is this model selected by the function?** I wonder particularly because after having run this function, I'm able to extract the best model of all models with different(!) sizes by determining a specific criterion (e.g., adjr2).

Related to this, I wonder: If I set, for example, nbest = 5 I understand that the function calculates the five best models for each model size (i.e., for a model with ten variables it gives five different variations that perform better than the rest). **If I understand that correctly, is there any way to extract these five models for a specific model size?** That is, for example, display the coefficients of these *five* best models?

I hope, I'm being clear about my problems here... Please, let me know, if exemplary data or any further information will help to clarify the issue!

Comment: This is a good question. I landed here looking for an answer to this question as well. This deserves more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" model picked by `regsubsets` is the one that minimizes the sum of the squares of the residuals.

I'm still working on the second question...

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the second question: the next code displays the coefficients of the 5 best models for each quantity of explanatory variables, from 1 to 3 variables. `Y` is the response variable of the models.

```
library(leaps)

best_models = regsubsets( Y ~ ., data = data_set, nvmax=3, nbest=5)
coef(best_models, 1:15)
```